# Simplify $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{d\mid u} \varphi(d)\cdot 2^{\frac{nr}{d}}$

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, combinatorial-number-theory

I have been trying to solve the following problem:

> Let $n$ and $r$ be positive integers. How many subsets of $\lbrace 1,2,\dots, nr\rbrace$ are there whose elements have a sum divisible by $n$?

Now, I have been making some calculations and arrived at the following expression, where $u$ is the largest odd divisor of $n$ and $\varphi$ is Euler's totient function:

$$\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{d\mid u} \varphi(d)\cdot 2^{\frac{nr}{d}}$$

Does anyone have an idea how to simplify this any further? Is that even possible?

Comment: You introduce $r$, and it appears in your formula, but it doesn't play any role in the problem statement. Perhaps you forgot to state that the subsets should have $r$ elements?

Comment: For $d=1$ there's a term $\frac{2^{nr}}n$, which will typically be greater then the total number of subsets, $2^n$ – is there a typo?

Comment: I'm sorry the set whose subsets are counted should run up to $nr$, I'll fix it